# How to get a particular service block process nested agents in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am working on a ticketing model framework, where we receive requests for single or bulk user account creation in an SAP system. The request is an agent which have multiple agents - user(s) inside it.
[image: Model Image]

So, as you can see in the image we have

**Source** - Request is coming from here.
**Delay(createRequestNo)** - A request no. is assigned to the Request at this block.
**Service(userCreation)** - User(s) are created at this block.
**Sink** - Request (agent) goes out from this block.
**resourcePool** - A team of 15 who works on creating user accounts. It is linked to service block.

Imagine a bulk request comes in to create 5 users.
How do the resources at the service block process the all 5 user agents which are inside a Request agent here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your Request agent that flows through the process flow has a number of Agents in it, but these don't need to be agents, they can be pure Java classes or requests can also simply carry a number of users to create.

It all depends on the granularity you require

[image]

To answer your question you can access the inside of the agents that travels through the process flow and use that to determine the delay or the number of resources to be seized as follow:

[image]

Just be sure that the Agent type in the advanced setting is set to the Agent type that you expect in this block. If you set the Source to create a specific agent type it will automatically update all the serially connected blocks for you.

Please note if the user creation process will vary for each user to be created you need a separate delay for each user... and thus it would be better to split into multiple agents for each user creation, and then have them seize, delay and release each resource separately.

With your current logic, they will all be seized and released at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @Jaco for such an elaborate effort in super quick time. Please find that the users in request may have different type for eg. Finance user, Manufacturing user etc. plus we might have to assign different roles to them. So, I wish to create them as agents inside a request instead of a collection. But that's a battle for another day. I would like to solve this problem (specific service block resources handling nested agent) first.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - but the only impactor more or different users inside a request would be a longer delay on the seized resource right? So you just upgrade the formula for the delay. 
At the end of the delay, at the onExit code you can again use the collections of users to create actual data entries or what ever it is you want to do. 
Does this resolve your question?

Comment: Ok, even if we go with that assumption that we will play with delay time to mimic the real scenario but is there any way to at least show that 5 resources are handling this request that has come in?

Comment: Yes - See my updated screenshot, I wrote it in the text but did not show it in the screenshot. You simply seize the number of resources equal to the number of users to create.

Comment: Thanks @Jaco-Ben - I applied it and checked using trace line. Works like a charm. 
Uploaded the model for future help.                 
cloud.anylogic.com/model/4d52664c-3d11-42fa-b800-fa151fbf5d62?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL

Comment: Thank you, remember to accept my answer if you found it useful, and upvote if you think it worthy ;-)